# mysql - select from 2 tables, count and group by column

Tags: mysql, select, count, where-clause

So I have 2 tables:

pages:

```
id    page    visit_id
1      6         65
2      7         65
3      2         66
4      10        67
```

visits:

```
id    flipbook    
65      april         
66      april         
67      may
```

I want to return how many pages were viewed for each flipbook:

```
april: 3 
may: 1
```

My query looks like this:

```
"SELECT a.flipbook, (SELECT count(b.page) from pages b WHERE a.id = b.visit_id) AS total FROM visits a GROUP BY a.flipbook"
```

But it returns:

```
april: 1 
may: 1
```

Because it gets only the last visit from april, where we visited one page.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.flipbook, count(*)
  from visits a 
    inner join pages p
      on a.id = p.visit_id
  group by a.flipbook
```

There are no need for subqueries - this is just a basic join and aggregate.

Comment: 9 mins ago? But I only just saw it :-(

Answer (score 1):

try to use query like this

```
SELECT a.flipbook,COUNT(*) AS total
FROM visits a 
LEFT JOIN pages b ON a.id = b.visit_id
GROUP BY a.flipbook
```

Answer (score 1):

Um, bit off track there...

```
SELECT v.flipbook
     , COUNT(*) pages_viewed 
  FROM visits v 
  JOIN pages p 
    ON visit_id = v.id 
 GROUP 
    BY v.flipbook;
```

Use an OUTER JOIN and count something else if you want '0' results too.

Answer (score 1):

you can try use query like this :

```
SELECT v.flipbook, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM pages p 
LEFT JOIN visits v ON p.visit_id=v.id 
GROUP BY v.flipbook
```